# Java program doesn't close after cronjob call

Tags: java, cron, jakarta-mail

i've written an Java program that retrieves Mails from my mail account.

This jar is called by a cronjob on a Ubuntu Server every 15 minutes.

cronjob:

> /bin/sh /root/scripte/cron_bugtracker.sh

cron_bugtracker.sh:

> java -jar /path/to/file.jar

The jar works fine but the program dosen't exit.

When I do `ps ax | grep java` it always shows  a lot java processes with `java -jar /path/to/file.jar` as command:

> 32208 ?        Sl     0:59 java -jar /path/to/file.jar

My Java-Program works like that:

1. In the main I call the constructor
2. In the constructor I call the Method that gets the mails with javax.mail.*
3. Then the program is finished...at least it should be

Does anyone know why the programm doesn't exit? Please help.

EDIT:

In the logfiles I found this:

"Control" is the name of my Main Class.

```
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.1-b03 mixed mode):

"Service Thread" daemon prio=10 tid=0xb76bd000 nid=0x292 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0xb76bb400 nid=0x291 waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0xb76b9800 nid=0x290 waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0xb7681c00 nid=0x28f in Object.wait() [0xa10ad000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0xa1585650> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0xa1585650> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0xb7680000 nid=0x28e in Object.wait() [0xa10fe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0xa1585228> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0xa1585228> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=10 tid=0xb7606000 nid=0x28c runnable [0xb77ae000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0xa1855398> (a java.lang.Object)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Folder.createMessage(POP3Folder.java:362)
        at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Folder.getMessage(POP3Folder.java:343)
        - locked <0xa18261a0> (a com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Folder)
        at javax.mail.Folder.getMessages(Folder.java:947)
        - locked <0xa18261a0> (a com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Folder)
        at javax.mail.Folder.search(Folder.java:1231)
        at Control.receive(Control.java:53)
        at Control.<init>(Control.java:29)
        at Control.main(Control.java:24)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0xb767a800 nid=0x28d runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0xb76bf800 nid=0x293 waiting on condition

JNI global references: 163

Heap
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 2907K [0xa1580000, 0xa1ad0000, 0xa6ad0000)
  eden space 4416K,  65% used [0xa1580000, 0xa1856e20, 0xa19d0000)
  from space 512K,   0% used [0xa19d0000, 0xa19d0000, 0xa1a50000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0xa1a50000, 0xa1a50000, 0xa1ad0000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 0K [0xa6ad0000, 0xa7580000, 0xb1580000)
   the space 10944K,   0% used [0xa6ad0000, 0xa6ad0000, 0xa6ad0200, 0xa7580000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 2688K [0xb1580000, 0xb2180000, 0xb5580000)
   the space 12288K,  21% used [0xb1580000, 0xb1820230, 0xb1820400, 0xb2180000)
No shared spaces configured.
```

Comment: If you could go ahead and isolate the piece of code that blocks...that would be great, yeah.

Comment: perhaps put some logging in and see where the code gets up to

Comment: If you start your java program yourself, it behaves as expected?

Comment: I think he was clear enough as to where the hang is. He mentions that the program doesn't exit; he doesn't mention that the program doesn't do what it's supposed to do. In fact, he states that the program works ("The jar works fine but the program doesn't exit").

Comment: @ilmiacs: If I start it with eclipse it works fine.

Comment: You can try and add `System.exit(1);` on the last line of your `main()` and see if it solves the problem, if it does - that means that you're right in your assumption and then you can debug it by using log printing to see which part continues running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a debug print at the very end of the program.
If you see the print, then it means that the main thread ends, but the program doesn't exit. I'm guessing that JavaMail has a thread left open (perhaps a Mail Session), that needs closing. Are you sure you're closing all resources before exiting?

Comment: It had took a while but I found out (with a lot println's) that sometimes the `session.getStore();` and other times the `store.getFolder("INBOX");` hangs up. I don't know how to solve the problem correctly. I wrote a shell script that kills the dead processes.

Comment: Have you tried executing a thread dump, like Frank suggested below? Might have saved you quite a bit of println's...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JURtzUHv Do I get that right that it has something to do with `java.nio.file.Files.createTempFile()`?

Answer (score 3):

Do a thread dump to find out what's still running: you can use jstack PID for that, if you're using the Oracle JVM.

Comment: +1 - good idea! it's done with: `$JAVA_HOME/bin/jstack -l [PID]> dump.txt` and then 
`kill -3 [PID]`

Comment: Either jstack or kill -3. But you need the output of the process to get the result of kill -3, whereas jstack prints the thread dump on its own output.

Comment: So, obviously, you're not exiting main, or even your class' constructor.

Comment: Is this a thread dump on the only running instance? I'd kill all the instances before starting a new one, to make sure there's no locking from the POP server involved.

Comment: +1 for actually suggesting a way to deal directly with the hang.

Answer (score 0):

Try to finish the JVM explicitly using when the job is done. This is the code to do this:

```
System.exit(0);
```

As iccthedral said, maybe there is some code that is blocking your program.

Comment: Downvoted as this obstructs what is potentially a resource leak. I wouldn't rush to explicitly exit a JVM as a workaround for unknown hangs.

Comment: +1 since it will be useful to see if the OP's assumption is correct, but Isaac is right - it will not help in detecting the source of the problem. A good answer would be a combinations of both your answers (TMHO).